# Writing a Custom IIS Directory Listing Module

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I'm currently looking to replace the in-built "DirectoryListingModule" in IIS 7.5 with a custom version to make the listing a little prettier. The problem is I cannot seem to find anything on the subject of writing a managed module to do this myself. I've read the IIS 7 module/handler tutorials over on [Microsoft's site](http://www.iis.net/learn/develop/runtime-extensibility/developing-iis-modules-and-handlers-with-the-net-framework), which are helpful albeit very basic. I've also seen [Mike Volodarsky's implementation](http://mvolo.com/get-nice-looking-directory-listings-for-your-iis-website-with-directorylistingmodule/) but unfortunately no source code is provided. The only other resources I can find link back to either Volodarsky's blog or the Microsoft page (which is also written by Volodarsky!). I guess what I'm saying is I don't know how to get from the basic module in the Microsoft tutorial to the directory listing functionality of Volodarsky's example.

If anyone can provide a hint on how to tackle this I'd be very grateful. Also please let me know if any of this isn't clear (I'm terrible at writing).

Thanks in advance :)

Edit - Just to be clear, I realise I have a lot of reading to do and am not looking for anyone to do my work for me.

Comment: SO is not there to do your work... go ahead and implement as much as you can... when you have a specific question then come back and ask.

Comment: I'm not looking for anyone to do my work, as I said above I have written a basic module by following the tutorial on MS, but from here I'm not sure how to proceed. My code resembles that of the MS example.

Comment: If Mike Volodarsky's implementation is managed, you can always disassemble it using ILSpy, JustDecompile, or any other decompiler to learn the code.

Comment: And whar exactly do you need ? You question is either not specific enough or it basically leads to someone doing your work.

Comment: That's a great idea Lex Li, thanks!

Comment: Lex Li can you post your comment as an answer please?

Answer (score 0):

Mike Volodarsky's implementation is really simple:

you create a module that intercepts requests to "directory" urls within your application.
This module will create a collection of object that rappresents directory structure and save it in the httpcontext

Then you load an aspx page which binds to the httpcontext saved content.

I don't get what you are asking for?

If you are not able to develop that module you can use [the Mike Volodarsky's one](http://mvolo.com/assets/pre-migration/mvolo-directorylisting-web-v2.1.zip) and just customize the aspx page...

Comment: The question being asked is not about being able to implement a solution alone.  It is looking for an implementation with source code.  The missing link of understanding is most often filled in by seeing how someone handled the issue in their program.  I for one, understand what you are saying but if asked I couldn't produce what seems to be so simple to you.  

Seeing a simple set of statements that do what you are saying eliminates the vagueness that leaves me wondering what does that mean.  Like most people including the author I guess, I can follow the logic of most code.

Answer (score 0):

The `PreRequestHandlerExecute` event in an ASP.NET Application is where you can process and replace the default IIS handlers.

You have two option:

1. Use the `Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute` event in the `Global.asax` file.
2. Write a custom `IHttpModule` and use the `OnPreRequestHandlerExecute` event.

Regardless of which method you prefer to use, you must ensure that the request is a directory not a file, other registered handler, and so on.
Use the below code to check for it:

```
if (!Directory.Exists(context.Request.PhysicalPath))
    return;
```